# Does the sentence "His confident visage hid insecurity" make sense?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives, sentence, metaphors

I was wondering if this sentence makes sense, and if it does, is the meaning of *visage* in this sentence metaphoric?

> His confident visage hid insecurity.

Answer (score 5):

It *is* correct, although I'd suggest a minor edit along the lines of:

> His confident visage hid (or *masked*) **his** insecurity (or insecurities).

Comment: I'd probably stick to a continuous form *was hiding* too, unless the context calls for this use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an acceptable sentence according to me at least.

Visage is appearance. Appearance is not the truth, it is a mask, a mere skin over something we cannot perceive. The perception of insecurity behind a confident mask is common phenomenon amongst those who consider appearance to be the final word; observe most movie stars and the half-sentient populace who follow them, then you would know this aspect of appearance being supreme to be true.

Cornbread-ninja suggests a minor edit which I think is unnecessary because i) visage or appearance does connote a mask too and ii) 'his' is not required because there is no ambiguity over subject in the sentence fragment provided. If there were other subjects in play within a larger sentence or context then Cornbread-ninja's suggestions would be valid.

Anyway, my first comment around here..please do guide if am missing the spirit of this site!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence makes perfect sense.  Whether *visage* here is metaphorical kind of depends on how you look at things.  This word is borrowed from French; and in French, *visage* means face.  *Usually* in English it means appearance or bearing, as indeed it does here.  So yes, it's absolutely a metaphor.  It's rare to find it not as a metaphor.